# Swing - How do I make a transparent JFrame with opaque content?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparency

My goal is to have a transparent JFrame with a non-transparent JPanel that is constantly drawing a square at a random place

```
private static final int alpha = 255;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, alpha));

    CustomPanel panel = new CustomPanel();

    panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();

        }

    }, 0, 1000);

    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static class CustomPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));
        g.fillRect((int)(Math.random() * 380), (int)(Math.random() * 320), 20, 20);
    }

}
```

Currently, the frame is rendered with a white background and the square is drawn correctly.

### **alpha = 255**

[image]

However, if I reduce `alpha` to 31, `clearRect` will not clear the JFrame background and it will start overlapping itself

### **alpha = 31**, 1 Iteration vs. 4 Iterations

[image]

As time goes on, the background will become more opaque as more copies are rendered over it.

Answer (score 1):

For a transparent panel don't use a transparent color. Swing does not paint backgrounds with transparency correctly. See [Background With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information.

However, for full transparency there is a simple solution. Just make the panel transparent:

```
//panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
panel.setOpaque( false );
```

Then in the painting code you would use:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
g.setColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));
g.fillRect((int)(Math.random() * 380), (int)(Math.random() * 320), 20, 20);
```

Note however you should NOT be using random values in a painting method. You can't control when or how often Swing will repaint a component.

Instead you need a property of the class to be the Color for the Rectangle. Then you need a method like `setSquareColor(...)` when you want to change the Color of the square.

Comment: After applying your changes, there is no difference. The problem is not within the panel. The problem is that when my JFrame is transparent, the paint method draws over the old frame, since the clear method only clears a small amount of alpha.

EDIT: I get the same issue with this https://pastebin.com/HPEVcfNe

Comment: @nathanthesnooper, 1) The alpha color suggestion would also apply to the frame. Instead you should be using the `setOpacity(...)` method of the JFrame 2) You should be using a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) not an AWT Timer. Swing components should be updated on the `Event Dispatch Thread`. 3) Your code doesn't compile there is no class or import statements.

Comment: 1) `setOpacity` also effects the content, and I want the content to have full opacity.
2) I have already fixed this and it does not seem to make a difference.
3) I ommited the class declaration and the import statements as they do not contribute to the question

Comment: @nathanthesnooper, `I ommited the class declaration and the import statements as they do not contribute to the question` - yes they are relevant so we can easily copy/paste/compile/test to verify your code. See: [mcve] for what is expected in this forum when posting code.  `setOpacity also effects the content` - not with the code I have on my machine (JDK 8 on Windows 7) it doesn't. If you post a proper "MCVE" maybe people using your environment will test it and people not using your environment can verity if it works or not.